# Underscore problem with long statement

Tags: underscore

I am writing a thesis, in which I have to add a a long statement, which look like this

```
a_b/a_b_r_M_M_l_o_f_A_a_A_A_A_Y_X_C_V_B_N_W
```

But to handle the underscore I added the above statement as follow

```
\begin{verbatim}a_b/a_b_r_M_M_l_o_f_A_a_A_A_A_Y_X_C_V_B_N_W\end{verbatim}
```

But the problem is, this statement cross page-width, this statement does not move to second line , like a normal text.

As I said, I would like to handle this line as a normal text. according to the page width it moves to next line, as normal text do.

Looking for help.

Comment: verbatim is not normal text. It only adds a line break if you explicitly put a newline there. So what do you want? Where do you want it to break?